# What is a efficient way to query for this information? [RoR]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Okay basically I'm trying to query the community_posts model and count the amount of posts where .community_topic_id is equal to community_topic which is a param. I was looking over the doc and I have a few ideas of how to do but, I want to make sure I'm doing it right as I have a few similar queries I'm writing for various other methods.

Hope this isn't too broad.. Not trying to ignite a "opinion war" I just want a way to do that wont turn out to be inefficient and force me to change my other queries.

Appreciate your help.

```
def topicreplycount(community_topic)
    "Code for query"
end
```

Comment: Try the RoR tutorial.  It covers this kind of stuff unambiguously, including how to set up your models and relationships.  Also, "I have a few ideas" isn't telling us what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CommunityPost.count(community_topic_id: community_topic)
```